# How to apply transform only in the parent element?

Tags: html, css, transform, css-transforms

I have HTML

```
<div id="mydiv" style="color: white; height: 1080px; width: 1920px; transform: translate(-27px, -323px) scale(0.972, 0.401);">
    <div class="player_controls">
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

This code contains the

```
transform: translate(-27px, -323px) scale(0.972, 0.401);
```

which apply to child element player_controls,a tags.

So can do something like not affect the child element?

I tried to remove transform from player_controls

```
#mydiv .player_controls{transform:''}
```

Comment: You'd have to reverse whatever transform is not required.

Comment: Not getting you. I just don't want to apply transform scale to child

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Child elements will always get affected by transform on the parent element. This is *not something that a child inherits* and hence it cannot be over-ridden by using `transform: ' '` or `transform: none` on the child. One way to counter it would be to apply the reverse transform on the child. Here, since the `scale` shouldn't affect the child, the inverse of the parent's scale should be applied to it.

The scaleX on parent is 0.972 and so the scaleX on child should be 1/0.972 (inverse) which is 1.028. Similarly for scaleY it shouldbe 1/0.401 which is 2.493.

```css
#mydiv,#mydiv2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  transform: translate(27px, 23px) scale(0.972, 0.401);
}

#mydiv .player_controls {
  transform: scale(1.028, 2.493);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<h2>With reverse transform on child</h2>
<div id="mydiv">
  <div class="player_controls">
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right">Some icon</span>Some text</a> 
  </div>
</div>
<h2>With no reverse transform on child</h2>
<div id="mydiv2">
  <div class="player_controls">
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right">Some icon</span>Some text</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If for whatever reason you are unable (or unwilling) to apply the reverse transform on the child element then you'd have to change your structure and make the child element a sibling element.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  transform: translate(27px, 23px) scale(0.972, 0.401);
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
}
.player_controls {
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  left: 27px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="mydiv">
  </div>
  <div class="player_controls">
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right">Some icon</span>Some text</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you judge value(1.028, 2.493) in scale?

Comment: That is, 1/parent's scale in X and Y axis.

Comment: If i don't want to scale element then?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. You should either reverse scale the child like in the snippet (or) change the structure to move the child outside of the parent and use absolute positioning. No other alternates.

Comment: My text keep changing when i change the resolution of window because through js transform rotate and scale set and it also change the player_controls text.I don't want to scale player_controls

Comment: @BhumiShah: If you are using JS to set the rotate or transform on the parent element then it should be easy for you to set the reverse on the child element also via JS, wouldn't it? I am not sure why you can't do it. Anyway, I have added a version that don't require a `transform` on `.player_controls` also.

Comment: No i am still waiting for solution

Comment: @BhumiShah: What part of the solution is not working? Can you create a demo based on the code that you tried? I can help correcting it. (By the way, as I mentioned earlier there are no alternates other than the two I've mentioned).